# How to assign foreach loop to a variable?

Tags: php, variables, foreach, foreach-loop-container

I have this following code.

```
$sn_count = 1;
  foreach($points as $point){
    echo "<div class=\"points\">";
    echo "<div class=\"serial\">".$sn_count."</div>";
    echo "<div class=\"pointsdesc\">";
    echo $point['points_description'];
    echo "</div></div>";
    $sn_count++;
  }
```

Is it possible to assign the above code to a variable `$pointsvar`

Everytime i use `$pointsvar` the above code should be printed. Please help.
Thanks

Comment: You mean like an include or a compiler constant?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Functions is your solution.

```
function printPointVars($points)
{
    $sn_count = 1;
    $html = '';
    foreach($points as $point){
        $html .= "<div class=\"points\">"
            . "<div class=\"serial\">".$sn_count."</div>"
            . "<div class=\"pointsdesc\">"
            . $point['points_description']
            . "</div></div>";
        $sn_count++;
    }
    echo $html;
}

printPointVars($points);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a function... not a variable

```
function pointvar() {
    //Your code here    
}
```

If you want get or set your variable

```
function pointvar($var = null) {
    if(!empty($var)) {
        $pointvar = $var;
    }
    //Your code here
    return $pointvar;
}

pointvar(12); //Set pointvar and execute your code
$newVar = pointvar(); //Get pointvar value and execute your code
```

Answer (score 0):

use .= to assign something to the end of a variable... Something like this:

```
$sn_count = 1;

$pointsvar = "";

foreach($points as $point){
  $pointsvar .= "<div class=\"points\">";
  $pointsvar .="<div class=\"serial\">".$sn_count."</div>";
  $pointsvar .="<div class=\"pointsdesc\">";
  $pointsvar .=$point['points_description'];
  $pointsvar .="</div></div>";
  $sn_count++;
}

echo $pointsvar;
```

If you want to call something like this alot, just move this into a function , and pass in the $points array.

Comment: And to make the format appear formatted in the browser; add `"\n"` to the end of each line.

Answer (score 0):

Is it ok if $pointsvar is static? (set once, then always at that value?) Is so, just change your echoes to become assignents...

```
$pointsvar = '';
$sn_count = 1; 
  foreach($points as $point){ 
    pointsvar = pointsvar."<div class=\"points\">"; 
    pointsvar = pointsvar."<div class=\"serial\">".$sn_count."</div>"; 
    pointsvar = pointsvar."<div class=\"pointsdesc\">"; 
    pointsvar = pointsvar.$point['points_description']; 
    pointsvar = pointsvar."</div></div>"; 
    $sn_count++; 
  }
```